# Why does my spring webapp using Freemarker get slower when I increase CPU core number?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, freemarker, scalability

I'm working on a spring webapp using Freemarker and I'm facing performance / scalability issues when I increase the number of CPU cores on our server.

In production, we have servers with the following configuration :

- Intel Xeon E5-2690
- 8 physical cores
- 2.9GHz up to 3.8GHz with Turbo Boost
- hyperthreading enabled

We bought new servers to replace old servers with the following configuration :

- Intel Xeon Gold 6254
- 18 physical cores
- 3.4GHz up to 4GHz with Turbo Boost
- hyperthreading disabled

The problem is : in a new server with 18 physical cores, our webapp is slower than in an old server with 16 cores (8 physical + hyperthreading) when we load the server with 500 jmeter threads.

So, we used Yourkit to profile our application and observed that a majority of tomcat ajp threads were blocked trying to acquire locks on tomcat SynchronizedQueue (or SynchronizedStack) when freemarker is processing templates and writing in the output :

[image: Thread blocked on this stack]

**The question is : why are these locks placed and how can we avoid or limit their impact on performances?**

Versions :

- Tomcat 9.0.14
- Spring 4.3.22
- Freemarker 2.3.28

Comment: Are you using Apache Tomcat APR Native Library ?

Comment: I *think* (but I'm not sure) that the new processor is a NUMA processor and the old one isn't. That means that there's probably some cross-zone memory access that slows you down ... Either using only cores/memory from one NUMA zone or having a fully NUMA aware software stack should solve the slowdown, if that's the issue.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I used "lscpu" command and I have "NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0-15" on the old server and "NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0-35" on the new server. So, they seem to be similar on this point.

Comment: @ThibautMallet: fair enough. However, I honestly don't know if that is definite proof or just an indication that your Linux kernel doesn't know the zones yet ;-)

Comment: Do you have a single or dual slot motherboard? If dual, did you populate only slot0 DRAM? Why don't you benchmark the system before running your app on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions to reduce significantly blocked threads on my webapp :

- I disabled freemarker autoflush calling `setAutoFlush(false)` ([see more](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setAutoFlush-boolean-))
- I optimized the way I process freemarker templates. Before then, my processTemplate method was :

```java
public void processTemplate(Template template, Map<String, Object> model, Writer writer) throws TemplateException, IOException {
  model.put(AbstractTemplateView.SPRING_MACRO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, new RequestContext(request, response, servletContext, model));
  template.process(model, writer);
}
```

each time a template was processed a new RequestContext was initialized : a lock is placed while the constructor is called.

Now, the RequestContext is initialized only once per request on the constructor of my FreemarkerProcessor :

```java
public FreeMarkerProcessor(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ServletContext servletContext, freemarker.template.Configuration freemarkerConfiguration) {
  this.freemarkerConfiguration = freemarkerConfiguration;
  requestContext = new RequestContext(request, response, servletContext, new HashMap<>());
}

public void processTemplate(Template template, Map<String, Object> model, Writer writer) throws TemplateException, IOException {
  requestContext.getModel().clear();
  requestContext.getModel().putAll(model);
  model.put(AbstractTemplateView.SPRING_MACRO_REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, requestContext);
  template.process(model, writer);
}
```